# Force workers to instantly pick up failed messages when persistent delivery mode is enabled

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I have a [RabbitMQ Server](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) set up where I fetch messages using [Python-Pika](https://github.com/pika/pika). The problem is that if I have [persistent delivery mode](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/MessageProperties.html) enabled, and the workers fails to process a message. Instead of releasing the message, it will keep it until the message  until the RabbitMQ connection has been reset.

Is there a way to make sure that the message that failed to process automatically gets picked up again within a reasonable time-frame from an available worker, including the same one?

**This is my current code**

```
if success:
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
else:
    syslog.syslog('Error (Callback) -- Failed to process payload: %s' % body)
```

The idea is that I never want to lose a message, instead I want it to get re-published, or rather picked up again if it failed. This should always be the case until the message has been successfully processed by a worker. This normally happens when one of the worker is unable to open a connection to the HTTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why this was happening. I did not realize that it wasn't enough to simply acknowledge when you were done with a message, but also had to reject any message you could not process using `channel.basic_reject`. This may seem obvious, but it is not the default behavior for [AMQP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html).

Basically we have to release the message using `basic_reject` with `requeue` set to `True`. The important factor here is the `requeue` keyword which prevents the message from being discarded, and instead queues it up again, so that one of our available workers can process it.

```
if success:
    # On Success - Mark message as processed.
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
else:
    # Else - Mark message as rejected and move it back to the queue.
    ch.basic_reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag, requeue=True)
```

I found some really useful information in [this](http://gavinroy.com/deeper-down-the-rabbit-hole-of-message-redeli) article, and there are more technical details on the `reject` keyword in [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/08/03/well-ill-let-you-go-basicreject-in-rabbitmq/) blog post.